# Change Laravel DataTables time format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my orders table, `created_at`  column saved in this format : `Y-m-d H:i:s`

But in the data table, it is displayed like this.

[image]

I add this code to the Order model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return is_null($date)
        ? ''
        : Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->timezone(config('app.timezone'))->toDateTimeString();
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return is_null($date)
        ? ''
        : Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->timezone(config('app.timezone'))->toDateTimeString();
}
```

But after this, the data table doesn't work and returns the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

How can I solve it?

Comment: did you try out ```cast``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of way to do that,  you can do it  from your controller as :

```
return Datatables::of($query)
  ->addColumn('created_at', function ($row){
       return $row->created_at->format('d-M-Y');
})
```

**Alternative** : Laravel 7 uses a new date serialization format when using the toArray or toJson method on Eloquent models.
Previously, dates would be serialized to a format like the following :

```
2020-12-02 20:01:00
```

Dates serialized using the ISO-8601 format will appear like :

```
2020-12-02T20:01:00.283041Z
```

If you would like to keep using the previous behavior you can override the `serializeDate()` method on your model :

```
use DateTimeInterface;

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

See the official upgrade doc  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

you can that  with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/datetime.format.php)

```php
$customDate='2020-12-02T20:01:00.283041Z';

$date=new DateTime($customDate);

echo $date->format('y-m-d H:i:s');
```